# FunctionalJava app throws StackOverflowError with Stream in stack trace

Tags: java, stack-overflow, functional-java

FunctionalJava app throws StackOverflowError with Stream in stack trace, but the app doesn't (seemingly) use stream. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly some other datastructure is useing Stream behind the scenes, which can use massive recursion.

The suspect in my case was `IterableW`, when using `wrap` and `bind` on native Java `Iterables`. Instead that, I used `fj.List.iterableList` to convert a finite `Iterable` to a `fj.List`, which has effective `bind` operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/pull/25) to fix this on github.

If this is biting you, perhaps you could try that fix, and vote +1 on merging it if it works for you?

Comment: Update: fix merged upstream